# Interfaz COM no encontrada en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy queriendo utilizar la libreria pyFEPDF, que genera un pdf de factura con formato para Argentina, y obtengo este error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found in /home/u390048254/domains/engrasecornalo.com/public_html/views/modules/facta/imprimeA.php:25

En algunos temas lei que hay que habilitar la extension COM en php.ini:

> [COM_DOT_NET]
> extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

Peromi aplicacion esta en un webhosting. Y no creo tener accesos al php.ini.
Pero que puede ser? De que manera puedo resolverlo?

Aqui una parte del codigo:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 $HOMO = true;   # homologación (testing / pruebas) o producción
 $CACHE = "";    # directorio para archivos temporales (usar por defecto)

try {
    
# Crear objeto interface Web Service Autenticación y Autorización
$PyFEPDF = new COM('PyFEPDF'); 

# CUIT del emisor
$PyFEPDF->CUIT = "33693450239";

# Establezco los valores de la factura a generar:
$fecha = date("d/m/Y");
$tipo_cbte = 1;                 # 1: factura A, 6: Factura B, 11: Factura C, 19 Factura E 
$punto_vta = 1;
$cbte_nro = 123;
 ....demas codigo
```

y el error esta aqui:

```
   $PyFEPDF = new COM('PyFEPDF');
```

Comment: [COM se ejecuta solo en servidores windows](https://www.php.net/manual/es/com.requirements.php) y, aparte, debe habilitarse desde _php.ini_. Dudo que puedas hacerlo en un servidor compartido.

Comment: Y si fuera un VPS, es decir sobre Linux... Tengo que cambiar ese codigo? Supongo mi hosting trabaja con Linux. Voy a revisar la documentacion

Comment: La extensión solo está disponible para servidores Windows, no importa si es compartido, VPS o dedicado, en Linux no va a funcionar.

Comment: Claro entiendo. Entonces ese codigo funciona sobre Windows. Y no hay manera de cambiar el codigo a un equivalente por asi decirlo.

Comment: Es decir instalar o correr la libreria pyfepdf sobre linux

Comment: Sino tendria que probar compilar la libreria que esta en python para Linux. Casi todos los servidores hoy trabajan con Linux

Comment: En todo caso, deberías transcribir la librería de _Python_ a _PHP_